# Sprite kit Coloring sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Hello I have two questions.
1. Is there a way that I can color only part of a sprite? So if there is a spaceship half will become red and the rest will stay the same.
2. How can I add a tint to a sprite? say I have a map of the world and the u.s.a is green like on a regular map I want to be able to colorize it but leave it semitransparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Unless maybe it's possible with a custom shader.
2. See color property https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/color

Comment: do you know if the first question is possible in Cocos2D?

Comment: no, but custom shader could/should work with any engine supporting shaders